# How to append only two columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

lets say I have the following data frame:

```
dt <- data.frame(id= c(1),
                 parameter= c("a","b","c"),
                 start_day = c(1,8,4),
                 end_day = c(16,NA,30))
```

[image]

I need to combine **start_day** and **end_day** columns (lets call the new column as **day**) such that I reserve all the other columns. Also I need to create another column that indicates if each row is showing start_day or end_day. To clarify, I am looking to create the following data frame

[image]

I am creating the above data frame using the following code:

```
dt1 <- subset(dt, select = -c(end_day))
dt1 <- dt1 %>% rename(day = start_day)
dt1$start <- 1

dt2 <- subset(dt, select = -c(start_day))
dt2 <- dt2 %>% rename(day = end_day)
dt2$end <- 1

dt <- bind_rows(dt1, dt2)
dt <- dt[order(dt$id, dt$parameter),]
```

Although my code works, but I am not happy with my solution. I am certain that there is a better and cleaner way to do that. I would appreciate any input on better alternatives of tackling this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
(tidyr::pivot_longer(dt, cols = c(start_day, end_day), values_to = "day")                                                        
    |> dplyr::mutate(start = ifelse(name == "start_day", 1, NA),                                              
                     end = ifelse(name == "end_day", 1, NA))                                                  
)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 6                                                                                            
      id parameter name        day start   end                                                                
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                                                                
 1     1 a         start_day     1     1    NA                                                                
 2     1 a         end_day      16    NA     1                                                                
 3     1 b         start_day     8     1    NA                                                                
 4     1 b         end_day      NA    NA     1                                                                
 5     1 c         start_day     4     1    NA                                                                
 6     1 c         end_day      30    NA     1
```

You could get rid of the `name` column, but maybe it would be more useful than your new `start`/`end` columns?

Comment: Thanks! I agree, the "name" column is a better way to keep information about the day.

Comment: If there are multiple  coliumns, an option is also to use `pivot_wider` after `pivot_longer` `pivot_longer(dt, cols = c(start_day, end_day), values_to = "day", names_transform = ~ str_remove(.x, "_day")) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = name, values_fn =  ~ +(length(.x) > 0))`

Answer (score 1):

using base R (faster than data.table up to ~300 rows; faster than tidyr up to ~1k rows) :

```
cbind(dt[1:2], day = c(dt$start_day,dt$end_day)) |> 
  (\(x) x[order(x$id, x$parameter),])() |> 
  (`[[<-`)("start", value = c(1, NA)) |>
  (`[[<-`)("end", value = c(NA, 1))
```

```
  id parameter day start end
1  1         a   1     1  NA
4  1         a  16    NA   1
2  1         b   8     1  NA
5  1         b  NA    NA   1
3  1         c   4     1  NA
6  1         c  30    NA   1
```

using the data.table package (faster than tidyr up to ~500k rows) :

```
dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt[,.(day = c(start_day, end_day), 
      start = rep(c(1, NA), .N), 
      end = rep(c(NA, 1), .N)), 
     by = .(id, parameter)]
```

```
   id parameter day start end
1:  1         a   1     1  NA
2:  1         a  16    NA   1
3:  1         b   8     1  NA
4:  1         b  NA    NA   1
5:  1         c   4     1  NA
6:  1         c  30    NA   1
```